# SQL ACCESS Multiple FK to same table id

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm getting

> Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected  1

My tables are:

```
Libro{
    idLibro
    fromNumber
    toNumber
    control1  > FK Persona
    control2  > FK Persona
}

Persona{
    idPersona
    name
}
```

Tried this 2 ways but got the same error

```
sql= "SELECT L.*, P.nombre as c1, Q.nombre as c2 
     FROM ((Libro L INNER JOIN Persona P ON P.idPersona = L.control1)
     INNER JOIN Persona Q ON Q.idPersona = L.control2)"
```

And

```
sql= "SELECT L.*, P.nombre as c1, Q.nombre as c2 
     FROM Libro L, Persona P, Persona Q 
     WHERE L.control1=P.idPersona AND L.control2=Q.idPersona"
```

Both tables have this values:

```
Libro{
    (1, 100, 150, 1, 3)
    (2, 151, 300, 2, 3)
}

Persona{
    (1, 'Juan')
    (2, 'Mario')
    (3, 'Luis')
}
```

What I expect is to get both names that *control1* and *control2* references in the registry from Libro

Comment: Perhaps you need `as` for defining the table aliases.

Comment: With or without  the " Libro _AS_ L" it gets the same error, sadly

Comment: This is a VBA run query. Can you post the full code so we can see execution? Alternatively, place SQL in a query window and run from there and see for what field prompts *Enter Parameter*?

Answer (score 0):

the table you are aliasing (p and q) do not have a column named [nombre], so access thinks they are parameters, and hence probably prompting you to enter a parameter when you try to run them. you used [name] not [nombre]. so either change the column name in you table which wouldn't be a bad idea, as [name] is a reserved word, or change your query:

```
SELECT L.*, P.name, q.name
FROM (Libro AS L INNER JOIN Persona AS P ON L.control1 = P.idPersona) INNER JOIN Persona AS q ON L.control2 = q.idPersona;
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. As you already figure out, I translated that from spanish to english to ask here, that's why name <>nombre, but I have it ok

Comment: so did that fix your problem or not?